# Angular 8 + RxJS and problem with combine flatMap and forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, rxjs6, flatmap

I'm trying to make multiple http requests depends of previous one and combine returned data to final result object.

I have two endpoints:

1. `/properties` which returns me something like that:

   ````
   { 
     "data":[ 
       { 
         "id":1,
         "name":"Property 1",
         "units":[ 
           { 
             "id":1,
             "name":"Property 1 - Unit 1",
           },
           { 
             "id":2,
             "name":"Property 1 - Unit 2",
           },
         ],
       },
       { 
         "id":2,
         "name":"Property 2",
         "units":[ 
           { 
             "id":3,
             "name":"Property 2 - Unit 3",
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }```
   ````
2. `/properties/${property.id}/units/${unit.id}/bookings` which returns me some object related to previous request for instance:

   ```
   {
     "data": {
       "id": 1
     },
     "meta": {
       "count": 5
     }
   }
   ```

What I would like to achieve is combine those two responses into one on single unit level.
Like this:

```
{
  [
    ...

    { 
      "id":2,
      "name":"Property 2",
      "units":[ 
        { 
          "id":3,
          "name":"Property 2 - Unit 3",
          "bookings_meta": {
            "count":5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I created something like this and it works fine:

```js
    list(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('/properties').pipe(
        map((results: any) => results.data),

        flatMap((properties: any[]) => {
          if (properties.length > 0) {
            return forkJoin(properties.map((property: any) => {
              return forkJoin(property.units.map((unit: any) => {
                return this.http.get(`/properties/${property.id}/units/${unit.id}/bookings`).pipe(
                  map(({ meta }) => {
                    unit.bookings_meta = meta
                    return unit;
                  })
                )
              }))
            }))
          }
          return of([]);
        })
      );
    }


    this.list().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
```

But I think it is not in 100% correct solution. 
I'm feeling there are too many `forkJoin` and maybe it shouldn't be there `flatMap`?

The requests for **bookings** between **units** should be independent.

Some one have an idea how to improve the code above?

Answer (score 1):

`forkJoin` will return data when all calls are finished and return result

```
const combined = Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get('https:// ...properties').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('https:// ..properties/${property.id}/units/${unit.id}/bookings')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
)

combined.subscribe(latestValues => {
    console.log( "latestValues" , latestValues );
});
```

**UPDATE:**

It is possible to transform items emitted by an Observable into another Observable by using the `flatMap` operator. It creates an inner `Observable` and flats its result to the outer stream.

```
list(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/properties')
        .flatMap(properties => properties.map(p => p.units.map(unit => 
        {
            this.http.get(`/properties/${property.id}/units/${unit.id}/bookings`)   
        })))
        .subscribe(res => { // some actions });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response but I can't use like that because as you could see I need a `property.id` and `unit.id` in the second request (where `property.id` for each requests in the scope will be the same and `unit.id` will change - because we have many units in single property).

Comment: @mits please, see my updated answer, feel free to create [stackblitz.com example](https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an answer for the observable hell :)

```
list(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('/properties').pipe(
    map((results: any) => results.data),

    mergeMap((properties: any[]) => forkJoin(
      properties.map((property: any) => forkJoin(
        property.units.map((unit: any) => this.http.get(`/properties/${property.id}/units/${unit.id}/bookings`).pipe(
          map(({ meta }) => ({ ...unit, meta }))
        ))
      )).pipe(map((units: any[]) => ({ ...property, units }))))
    ))
  );
}
```

Cheers!